# Rest API with same HTTP status code, different error responses for one endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, rest, microservices, openapi, springdoc

We are developing our microservices using *Spring Boot* and *OpenAPI*.

**Each endpoint** could possibly return **many business exceptions** (an `errorCode`) and their **HTTP *Status Code*s** are all **the same** (say 400).

Below is a pseudo code of one of the endpoints:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/services")
public interface MyRestController {
    @PostMapping("/service1")
    HttpResponse executeService(HttpRequest request) 
                throws FirstBusinessException, SecondBusinessException;

}
```

And one of the following HTTP Responses would be returned, depending on the exception which occurred:

```
{
    "errorCode": "FirstBusinessException",
    "message": "A simple message for FirstBusinessException",
    "errorParams": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
     }
}
```

---

```
{
    "errorCode": "SecondBusinessException",
    "message": "A simple message for SecondBusinessException",
    "errorParams": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

- Status Code in both of the HTTP Header Responses are 400

We want to present it in our OpenAPI documentation, as it is important to us to tell our clients about each possible error of each endpoint.

Currently our workaround solution is documenting a list of all possible exceptions of the endpoint in its `description`.

---

Now I have following questions:

1. Is there any better (more standard) solution to this workaround?
   (I would appreciate if you could demonstrate it with `springdoc-openapi` way of doing it)
2. I've also seen  [anyOf/oneOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) feature that has been added since *OpenAPI V3*, but it requires different schemas. Should we really use different schemas for our exceptions (Instead of having a single one with for example *errorCode*, *message*, and *errorParam* fields, like above) ?

Comment: [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807.html) might be what you are looking for. Zalando created the [Problem library](https://github.com/zalando/problem) which integrates into Spring and provides the [Problem class](https://github.com/zalando/problem/blob/main/problem/src/main/java/org/zalando/problem/Problem.java) which you can use to generate appropriate [payloads](https://www.baeldung.com/problem-spring-web)

Comment: @RomanVottner Thank you for your response, but in this case I'm actually looking for a way to tell my API clients, the exact **error codes** that may occur for **one endpoint**, while all these error codes have the **same HTTP status code** in the response header. And I want to know that is there a standard way of doing so using OpenAPI specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Spring's `@ControllerAdvice`.  Something like this

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FirstBusinessException.class)
    public HttpResponse handleFirstBusinessException(FirstBusinessException ex, HttpRequest request) {
        ... do logic and return response
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SecondBusinessException.class)
    public HttpResponse handleSecondBusinessException(SecondBusinessException ex, HttpRequest request) {
        ... do logic and return response
    }
}
```

This allows you to return the same `HttpStatus` for both errors, but a custom error message and/or response entity for each.

Then, in your openApi documentation, you can set it up like this

```yaml
'400':
  description: You have made an invalid request
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: "#/components/schemas/ExceptionOne"
          - $ref: "#/components/schemas/ExceptionTwo"
      examples:
        Exception One:
          value:
            Exception: invalid Id Provided
            Provided ID: My ID 1
            Message: don't do that
        Exception two:
          value:
            Exception: incomplete request
            message: missing one or more fields within your json request
default:
  description: unexpected error
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
```

When you provide multiple examples, this provides a drop down in your ui (I'm using swagger here) to show your users what the various responses may look like.

[image]

You can use these responses and their titles to better explain.  For example, instead of calling it `ExceptionOne` you could call it `Missing ID`, or `Duplicate ID`.

If this doesn't work for you, another option is to make use of markdown syntax in your description to make your description more robust.  For example:

```yaml
description: |
  # You have made an invalid request
  
  ## Exceptions contained here include:
  1. Bad ID
  2. Your json failed validation
  3. You can't follow instructions
  
  | exception | fix | 
  | --- | --- |
  |badId | fix ID|
  | failed validation | read validation error message |
  | can't follow instructions | read better |
  
  ---
  
  If these are in error, contact us:</br>
  **phone**: 555-555-5555 </br>
  **email**: us@help.com
  
  Have a nice day.
```

will render as

[image]

Comment: This works fine, but in the end in OpenAPI documentation, you only have one response with your status code

Comment: I've edited it to include presentation of the information to the clients

Comment: first thank you for adding more info. For now I think these are the only two options to do so. But I think these parts are not enough for code generators and tools, to rely on them as a main part of the API. I think OpenAPI still lacks of a feature to cover such situation.

Comment: This is a commonly requested feature.  This ticket at github is 
 seven years old:  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/270.  The answers there say to use the `allOf` and `oneOf` options to do what you are requesting.   You stated that this requires different schemas.  I'd argue that if you are trying to reuse the same schema for the same response code and different messages, then you probably need to change the schemas.  Otherwise, the examples option I posted above works for that.